# split homepage into two columns

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I'm creating a homepage for my website and want a logo (avatar) to appear on the left hand side of the page and a login form to appear on the right hand side. My current code displays a centered login box and avatar. The avatar is directly above the login box (and slightly offscreen).

Ideally I'm looking to replicate facebooks homepage theme (facebook.com)

Any ideas?

html

```
{% load static %}
{#<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'homepage/style.css' %}">#}


<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "homepage/style.css" %}">
    <body>
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="{% static "homepage/images/my_logo.png" %}"
                     class="avatar"
                     alt=""
                     width=""
                     height="">
            </div>
            <div class="login-box">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form>
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
                    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
                    <a href="#">Sign-up</a><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background: black center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
}

.login-box{
    float: right;
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.login-box p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.login-box input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightgray;
    color: #000;
}

.login-box a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: darkgrey;
}

.login-box a:hover {
    color: #ffc107;
}
```

Comment: Remove the float styling, absolute positioning, tops and lefts. Your "rows" class is currently unused. Use a parent class to position the avatar and login form. You can position the two children elements of "rows" using a display of flex or using display grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of placing two items side by side across the screen. The first uses display grid, and outlines 2 columns, the second is using flex.

```css
img{
  height: 50vh;
}

.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  height: 50vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200" alt="">
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="paswd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwd">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200" alt="">
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="paswd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwd">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```